# Do i need hreflang or rel for translations in different domains?

Tags: seo, wordpress, duplicate-content, translation

I have a page in russian and I've decided to translate it using a completely different domain, so that it can be easier to remember. However, I'm using a page builder (elementor) which makes it really annoying and tricky to go page by page linking them with hreflang or rel.

What are the pros of doing it? Will i get better ranking (will google use my russian page value to give some push to the new domain?)

If i don't do it, will i get penalized for duplicate content? (Consider I manually translate rather than using Google Translate).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the pros of doing it? Will i get better ranking (will google
> use my russian page value to give some push to the new domain?)

By using `hreflang` you are helping **[Google determine the target localization of your content](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites#how-does-google-determine-a-target-locale)**:

> **How does Google determine a target locale?**
>
> Google relies on a number of signals to determine the best target audience for a page:
> ...
>
> `hreflang` statements, whether in tags, headers, or sitemaps.

> If i don't do it, will i get penalized for duplicate content?

**[Quite possible](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions)**:

> Localized versions of a page are only considered duplicates if the
> main content of the page remains untranslated.

Read more **[Avoid creating duplicate content](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/duplicate-content)**:

> Duplicate content generally refers to substantive blocks of content
> within or **across domains** that either completely match other content in
> the same language or are appreciably similar.